# How to get just one parameter in 'clip' CSS property using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is a really short question, but needed:

I need to get just one parameter of this '*clip*' CSS property

```
clip:rect(260px, 160px, 260px, 0px);
```

in this case I'd need to get the '**260px**' parameter only and set it equal to a variable '**x**', how do I get that one only?

Remember I'm using **Jquery** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some string manipulation on the property:

```
var clip = $("#bulb_light").css("clip"); // rect(260px 160px 260px 0px)
var clipTop = clip.split(' ')[0].replace("rect(", ""); // 260px
```

Comment: Ok, it's right again man :) But, can you explain me what it technically does? It's something like "I got these 4 items, so the first is @ [0], then I can replace it with " " but how do I get it back, the 260px? More properly: why? @RGraham